# ¿Cómo obtener las propiedades de una interface en typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, type

Buen día, comunidad, tengo una interface en TypeScript y quiero obtener todas sus propiedades, ojalá con sus tipos, en una estructura que pueda imprimir o mostrar. Por ejemplo:

```
interface carro {
 marca : string
 motor : {
  ref : number
  modelo : string
 }
}
```

Intente imprimirla directamente lo cual me da un error de querer usar una interface como un value. ¿Existe alguna función de Object que me retorne las propiedades?
Gracias

Comment: En Programacion Orientada a Objetos las interfaces son una plantilla de metodos y propiedades que en si misma no tiene constructor. El error que le sale es porque para que una Interfaz se instancie debe hacerse a través de una clase que la implemente. Debe implementar la interfaz con una clase, instanciar la clase y referenciarla a través de una variable miembro o local (del tipo de la interfaz)

Comment: Gracias por el aporte Mauricio, me gustaría saber si hay una forma de instanciar el objeto con la interface y que todas las props tengan un valor o que al fin de cuentas de manera rápida pueda obtener todas las propiedades que definí en la interface, o si, por el contrario, no existe esa posibilidad y es obligatorio instanciar el objeto asignándole un valor a todas las propiedades para poder luego acceder a sus nombres.

Comment: Le recomiendo que amplié la información que esta proporcionando en su pregunta; específicamente el código que está ejecutando para lo que usted nombra como "imprimir directamente" y que es lo que llama "obtener las propiedades" porque no me queda claro ¿Qué datos desea obtener si aún no ha instanciado un objeto que implemente la interfaz? El código que tiene publicado es la declaración de una interfaz; eso en si mismo no es instanciamiento ni asignación de valores

Answer (score 0):

Yo resolví mi problema de la siguiente manera, pero espero poder encontrar mejores respuestas.

Interfaces:

```
export interface UserInterface {
rutUsuario: string
nombreUsuario: string
correoUsuario: string
contrasenaUsuario: string
direccionUsuario: string
}

export type CorreoUsuario = Pick<UserInterface, 'correoUsuario' >
```

Controlador:

```
// Mostrar el correo del usuario según su rut
export const getCorreoUsuario = async (rutUsuario: string): Promise<CorreoUsuario[]> => {
const usuarios: UserInterface[] = await usuario.findAll({ where: { 
rutUsuario: rutUsuario
}})

//console.log(usuarios["correoUsuario"])

// Mapeo a solamente el correo del usuario
const correoUsuario: CorreoUsuario[] =
usuarios.map(({ correoUsuario }) => {
  return {
    correoUsuario
  }
})

return correoUsuario
}
```